# PowerShell: Manipulate existing variable field values

Tags: powershell

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but my mind's gone blank.....

I have the following output

```
PS C:\Users\User1> $TargetComputers

ComputerName   UninstallString                                                                               
------------   ---------------                                                                               
Server1        MsiExec.exe /I{A7E794A1-D6E9-43CC-9B69-DEB6B5A91EF9}                                          
Server2        MsiExec.exe /I{36648B37-EA03-4349-8C49-C26032D06C61}                                          
Server3        MsiExec.exe /I{36648B37-EA03-4349-8C49-C26032D06C61}                                          
Server4        C:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe                                                          
Server5        MsiExec.exe /I{A7E794A1-D6E9-43CC-9B69-DEB6B5A91EF9}                                          
Server6        MsiExec.exe /I{A7E794A1-D6E9-43CC-9B69-DEB6B5A91EF9}                                          
Server7        {"D:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe", MsiExec.exe /I{36648B37-EA03-4349-8C49-C26032D06C61}}
Server8        MsiExec.exe /I{A7E794A1-D6E9-43CC-9B69-DEB6B5A91EF9}                                          
Server9        MsiExec.exe /I{36648B37-EA03-4349-8C49-C26032D06C61}
```

How do I manipulate the UninstallString column to leave me just {GUID}, including literal path where specified, when I call $TargetComputers?

Comment: for most of those line, split on the `{`, take the 2nd part, split on the `}` and take the 1st part. for the lines that don't start with 'MsiExec.exe`, you will need to adjust what part you take after the splits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Sample data
$TargetComputers = @(
    @{ ComputerName='server1'; UninstallString='MsiExec.exe /I{A7E794A1-D6E9-43CC-9B69-DEB6B5A91EF9}' }
    @{ ComputerName='server1'; UninstallString='{"D:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe", MsiExec.exe /I{36648B37-EA03-4349-8C49-C26032D06C61}}' }
    @{ ComputerName='server1'; UninstallString='C:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe' }
) | % { [PSCustomObject] $_ }

$TargetComputers | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.UninstallString = $_.UninstallString -replace '.*/I{(.+?)}.*', '$1' 
}

$TargetComputers
```

Output:

```
ComputerName UninstallString
------------ ---------------
server1      A7E794A1-D6E9-43CC-9B69-DEB6B5A91EF9
server1      36648B37-EA03-4349-8C49-C26032D06C61
server1      C:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe
```

Explanation:

- By using the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator) operator, we are using regular expression (RegEx) pattern matching. The 1st string after `-replace` is the search string, the 2nd string is the substitute. If the RegEx doesn't match, the original string will be returned.
- RegEx search string breakdown:

  - `.*` - any character, zero or more times
  - `/I{` - literal sub string
  - `(` - starts a capture group

    - `.+?` - any character, one or more times, as little as possible
  - `)` - ends the capture group
  - `}` - literal sub string
  - `.*` - any character, zero or more times
- RegEx substitute:

  - `$1` - replaces the string with the content of the 1st capture group (the GUID value)

Comment: Thanks for this and the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$TargetComputers = $TargetComputers | ForEach-Object {
  $matches = [Regex]::Matches($_.UninstallString, ({.*}),"IgnoreCase")
  if ( $null -ne $matches.Groups ) {
    $_.UninstallString = $matches.Groups[1].Value
  }

  return $_
}
```